# Why is data not saved with SharedPreferences in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I faced such problem that lock data in file is from shared_prefs folder and also loaded from it. However, when I exit the application, the text from my TextView disappears.

Below I am attaching the code from onCreate, LoadText and onPause()

```
String result_1 = edit.getText().toString();

if(result_1.isEmpty()){       
    result_2 = 0;
} else {
    result_2 = Integer.parseInt(result_1);      
}

result_products += result_2;

String result_full = Integer.toString(result_products); 

sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SAVE", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("TEXT", result_full);
editor.apply();
                    
LoadText();

...

protected void LoadText() {
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SAVE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    TextView textView_products = findViewById(R.id.textView_products);
    String savedText = sharedPreferences.getString("TEXT", result_full);
    textView_products.setText(savedText);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SAVE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("TEXT", result_full);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: It's always either permissions or attribute type, what's the value you have for result_full? I see you're adding result_2 to result_products, your parsing the results to a string 'result_full'; can you print/console the result_full that's failing to save? am curious what it is; could be a clue

Comment: @IlanP Now I will try to explain what I am doing with this code. This is a financial application. The user enters a number (result_1) into the EditText and clicks the Save button. result_2 is needed in order to sum up all the numbers entered by the user. result_products is the total sum of the entered numbers. Next, I create a result_full to already work with the String and display it in a TextView (textView_products)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're overwriting it right before calling LoadText(). This causes the old value to be lost.

Comment: but the value is written to SAVE.xml

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Right before you load the data, you're overwriting it.  That means the old value is lost.  So when you load it, you're loading the data you just wrote, which is not what you wanted to load, and likely not correct.